# Download all the files in different formats using Python from a website

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

How to download all the datasets in .csv, .xlsx, .json format from a website using python. I need to download thousands of files, after finding them, to my computer. Could you please help me to automate the process. The data is by city so it can be generalized for further uses.
How about Using MECHANIZE?

Comment: There is a python library call urlretrieve which you may be inteested in. https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve

Comment: I was thinking of using mechanize to detect all the links in webpage that have some files and then download all such files. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `selenium webdriver`, it will be the best way for web scraping without a limit. But you need to be more specific what you ask. If there are links to download only in one url, it is easy. But if all download links are in different url's, it will take a little time, I guess.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(website)
browser.find_element_by_name("file_name_to_download").click()
```

That's it. Of course, you need to create a simple loop to click all download links one by one.

Comment: Thanks @hzleonardo